# How to get actionbar for activities styled as dialog with appcompat-v7 22.1?

Tags: android, android-appcompat

Some background: I'm adding tablet support for a game that's previously been available on phones for a long time. Some of the activities make up a “wizard” where the user chooses game type, some options, and an opponent before the game can start. For the tablet version using a theme inheriting  `Theme.AppCompat.DialogWhenLarge` for these activities looked like a good, easy solution. This worked fine when using appcompat-v7 version 22.0.0.

In appcompat-v7 version 22.1, in all these *DialogWhenLarge* activities, suddenly `getSupportActionBar()` started returning `null` on tablets. I was relying on the actionbar for back navigation and more importantly for Search and other buttons.

What's the appropriate way to get an action bar on these activities on tablets? Do I need to implement my own toolbar?

I have tried calling `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR)` in my `onCreate` (before calling super) but that has no effect. I tried subclassing from `AppCompatActivity` instead of `ActionBarActivity` but that didn't help either (both with and without requestWindowFeature).

I have read [Chris Banes' blog post](https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/) on this new library version as well as [Ian Lake's post](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) on the Android Developers Blog; I couldn't see anything mentioning that actionbars should no longer be available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. The only way I could find to fix it was to replace the action bars with toolbars.

```
// Replace the action bar with a toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

My toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/DefaultActionBarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

included in my activity:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/detail_root"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include android:id="@+id/tool_bar" layout="@layout/tool_bar" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/detail_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="always" />
</LinearLayout>
```

DefaultActionBarTheme (in styles.xml):

```
<!-- Action bar theme -->
<style name="DefaultActionBarTheme" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#1d7caf</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks @Henri. I tried this, and it caused the activity's menu to be included in the toolbar so that's a good beginning, but there's still a title bar at the top of the dialog, above the custom toolbar. Did you not have this problem?

Comment: I solved this last problem with ```<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>``` in my DialogWhenLarge-derived theme.

Comment: Yes I had that same problem. Your solution is the same one I used. I traced up through the parent themes and `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` is set in `Platform.AppCompat.Light` but it seems you have to use just *windowNoTitle* without the *android:* in AppCompat themes for it to work properly.